# As use mqtt on Expo?

Tags: android, ios, node.js, expo, mqtt

I'm having a hard time figuring out the right way to go when adding MQTT to a expo project I have. The project needs to run on iOS and Android, so ideally the MQTT can be handled in the javascript side. I'm tested the MQTT.js but returns the error:

[image]

Comment: I use this package and it works more or less in my react native expo setting: https://github.com/rh389/react-native-paho-mqtt. Unfortunately it doesn’t have types.

Comment: Did you see this voting? https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/add-mqtt-support. Please upvote 